# Gremlin BFS enumeration including root

Tags: gremlin

I want to include the root node in the output for the following Gremlin expression:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).as('x').out.loop('x'){true}{true}
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
```

So that the output includes v[1] as well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You are using an outdated version of TinkerPop. Any reason you're not using TinkerPop 3? If not, I strongly suggest updating (see http://tinkerpop.apache.org/).

Comment: I am on TinkerPop 3 as I am currently on OrientDB and I believe they are still om TP3? How would Tinkerpop3 change the answer to this question?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - this is TinkerPop 2 Gremlin syntax :). TinkerPop 3 is a complete rewrite and offers a much richer API. If you're just getting started with graphs, learning Gremlin 2 is probably not worth the trouble. The `.gather()/.scatter()` pattern is gone in TP3 and was replaced by the `.barrier()` step in OLTP, so this is how it changes the answer. Note that in OLAP, Gremlin 3 is inherently breadth-first search.

Comment: Note that there is a TinkerPop 3.x implementation over OrientDB managed here: https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin - you might find that useful for your purposes

Comment: The gather()/scatter step in this pipeline is redundant, as pointed out in this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828841/breadth-first-enumeration-in-gremlin/17833088#comment36626158_17833088 . While I will definitely consider migrating my codebase to TP3, but I am not the one deciding this. So an answer for TP2 will still be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible solutions in TinkerPop 2.x First one that uses [store()](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#store):

```
gremlin> x=[];g.v(1).store(x).as('x').out.loop('x'){true}{true}.store(x).iterate();x        
==>v[1]
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
```

Here's a second that doesn't explicitly force creation of an external variable that uses `transform` and a closure:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).transform{[it] + (it._().as('x').out.loop('x'){true}{true}.toList())}.scatter()    
==>v[1]
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
```

For those using TinkerPop 3.x, simply place the `emit()` in front of the `repeat()`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).emit().repeat(out())
==>v[1]
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
```

Comment: I was actually hoping for a solution that did not require intermediate variables, so I would be able to use the query with the OrientDB gremlin query executor. But I think I'll have to run two separate queries in the end..

Comment: is it better with transform/scatter as shown in the edited answer above?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!