# DSE Graph with Java Driver, how to walk through a graph (like a tree)

Tags: java, cassandra, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I have a subgraph where I know how to come to the root vertex. But then I need to walk through it.

Concretely "walk through the subgraph" in my case means that I have to walk to all leafs of the subgraph (because I know that the subgraph is like a tree) and then go the path back and do some calculations between every vertex.

My question is, how to achieve that in the most performant way?

I can think about two solutions.

First, I walk through the graph with plenty of `session.executeGraph("g.V().has('id','1')").one()` statements to get all the single vertices and edges and do the calculations with them. But I think this way is very inefficient.

Or I work with the path object that I can get with

```
GraphNode node = session.executeGraph("g.V().has('id','1').repeat(outE().subgraph('sg').otherV()).cap('sg').path()").one();
Path path = node.asPath();
```

I am quite sure, the second solution is the preferred one but I have no clue how to use the path object to walk through the graph because the only thing I can see is a flat map of objects.

## Update #1

[image]

Here is a picture of an example tree. The goal, I need the "combined value" for node A. The rules are quite simple. The nodes (except the root) has values. The edges has weightings. I have to sum all values regarding the weights. As long as a child has only one parent I can take the complete value. In case a child has multiple parents, I have to take the weighting into account. In the example tree, the combined value of **B** would be
`100 + (500 * 50/60) + 1000` and the combined value of **A** would be `combined value of B plus value of C` (**A** == 2156.67). So, I need properties from the vertices and the edges for the calculation.

## Update #2

So, here is my solution.

I've implemented an abstract Tree class that is doing the actual calculation (because I also have a mock implementation).

```
public abstract class Tree {
    // String == item id
    protected final Map<String, Item> items = new HashMap<>();
    private final String rootItemId;

    protected Tree(String rootItemId) {
        this.rootItemId = rootItemId;
    }

    public void accumulateExpenses() {
        accumulateExpenses(null, null);
    }

    private double accumulateExpenses(String itemId, String parentItemId) {
        final Item item = itemId == null ? items.get(rootItemId) : items.get(itemId);
        final double expense = item.getExpense();
        double childExpenses = 0;

        for (String childId : item.getChildIds()) {
            childExpenses += accumulateExpenses(childId, item.getId());
        }

        // calculate the percentage in case the item has multiple parents
        final double percentage = item.getPercentage(parentItemId);
        final double accumulatedExpenses = percentage * (expense + childExpenses);
        item.setAccumulatedExpense(accumulatedExpenses);

        return accumulatedExpenses;
    }
}
```

And I've implemented a GraphTree class that is responsible to fill the item map of the super class (abstract tree).

```
public class GraphTree extends Tree {
    public GraphTree(GraphNode graphNode, String rootNodeId) {
        super(rootNodeId);

        final GraphNode vertices = graphNode.get("vertices");
        final GraphNode edges = graphNode.get("edges");

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            final Vertex vertex = vertices.get(i).asVertex();
            final Item item = Item.fromVertex(vertex);
            super.items.put(item.getId(), item);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
            final Edge edge = edges.get(i).asEdge();
            final Relation relation = Relation.fromEdge(edge);
            super.items.get(relation.getParentId()).getRelations().add(relation);
        }
    }
}
```

For sake of completeness, here is also the Item class.

```
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private double accumulatedExpense;
    private final List<Relation> relations = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<String, Expense> expenses = new HashMap<>();

    public void setAccumulatedExpense(double accumulatedExpense) {
        this.accumulatedExpense = accumulatedExpense;
    }

    public double getPercentage(String parentId) {
        if (parentId == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        double totalWeight = 1;
        double weight = 1;

        for (Relation relation : relations) {
            if (Objects.equals(id, relation.getChildId())) {
                totalWeight += relation.getWeight();
                if (Objects.equals(parentId, relation.getParentId())) {
                    weight = relation.getWeight();
                }
            }
        }

        return weight / totalWeight;
    }

    public static Item fromVertex(Vertex vertex) {
        final Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(IdGenerator.generate(vertex));

        return item;
    }

    public List<String> getChildIds() {
        return relations.parallelStream()
                   .filter(relation -> Objects.equals(relation.getParentId(),id))
                   .map(Relation::getChildId)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

To get the initial subgraph, I've used the following code.

```
    final String statement = String.format("g.V('%s').repeat(outE().subgraph('sg').otherV()).cap('sg')", rootNodeId);
    final GraphNode node = session.executeGraph(statement).one();
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a breadth first search ? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17833088/1457059) shows quite a nifty approach. It would be simple to pass that gremlin query into DSE graph.

Comment: Thanks @Fido. But the problem I have is not how to get the graph (that works fine with the second query) but how to work with it with the Java Driver. Because what I get back is a `GraphNode` that has a flat `Map` containing all vertices and edges. So I lose all the important relations between the vertices. What I expected is something like `node.getOutEdges().forEach(edge -> edge.getInVertices())` and so on. So my main problem is how to work with the Java Driver properly. I am quite new to gremlin but I think I understood it so far, but I can't transfer it to Java as I expected.

Comment: What is the ultimate result you're looking for? It sounds like you won't even need the paths, but only certain properties, that you're then going to accumulate.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz: I've updated my question. I hope now it is clearer what I have to accomplish. But maybe you are right and I can achieve that with a sophisticated gremlin statement. In that case I have to learn more about gremlin I fear :)

Comment: Thanks, the update makes it clearer. Still one question though: In the result you only expect B and its value 1516.67. C is not included, because it has no child nodes and other nodes are not included, because they are no direct children of A. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was too lazy to complete the calculation :) You are right, nodes like **Z** are not included because they are not a child of **A**. But **C** also has to be included into the calculation. So the combined value of **A** would be `combined value of B plus C`. **A** == 2516.67

Answer (score 2):

Even after reading the comments over and over again, I'm confused by the logic when I try to find a solution using a single query. Hence it's probably best to just tell you how to get a tree representation:

```
g.V().has('id','1').repeat(outE().as("e").inV()).emit(__.not(outE())).tree()
```

If you only need certain information (e.g. the `value` property of vertices and the `weight` property of edges), you can do this:

```
g.V().has('id','1').
  repeat(outE().as("e").inV()).emit(__.not(outE())).
  tree().by("value").by("weight")
```

And since vertex `A` doesn't seem to have a `value` property, you'll need to add a `coalesce` step:

```
g.V().has('id','1').
  repeat(outE().as("e").inV()).emit(__.not(outE())).
  tree().by(coalesce(values("value"), constant(0))).by("weight")
```

**UPDATE**

In case I need to play with the sample graph later again, here's the code to create it:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV().property(id, "A").as("a").
  addV().property(id, "B").property("value", 100).as("b").
  addV().property(id, "C").property("value", 200).as("c").
  addV().property(id, "D").property("value", 500).as("d").
  addV().property(id, "E").property("value", 1000).as("e").
  addV().property(id, "Z").property("value", 900).as("z").
  addE("link").from("a").to("b").property("weight", 80).
  addE("link").from("a").to("c").property("weight", 20).
  addE("link").from("b").to("d").property("weight", 50).
  addE("link").from("b").to("e").property("weight", 40).
  addE("link").from("z").to("d").property("weight", 10).iterate()
```

Comment: I am sad, that I can't describe my problem in a better way. But you helped me already in the sense that I think I can (have to?) solve the problem with one or more tricky gremlin statements only. So, I have to dig much deeper into gremlin. I will use your statements as a starting point. Thanks! Maybe one more question would be helpful for me ... do you think I should solve the problem with gremlin or within Java?

Comment: You mean Groovy or Java? Up to you, personally I prefer to use Java.

Comment: I mean, should I do de calculation (including the tree traversal) in gremlin or should I just read the subgraph and do the calculation in Java?

Comment: Oh, yea, that's probably much easier. Perhaps post your solution, once you get the correct results. I will then look at it again to see if we can turn that into a single Gremlin query.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I will post the code as far as I have the solution implemented.

Comment: So, I've updated the question with my solution. Don't put to much effort to create a proper gremlin statement. I know it is a bit complex. If you can confirm, that just getting the subgraph with gremlin and afterwards doing the complex stuff within Java is okay, I am completely happy. PS: I've striped down my code and removed all unnecessary stuff, hope it is understandable.

Comment: Looks good to me. `tree()` would probably be easier to handle than `subgraph()`. Also, if you run into performance issues, consider to select only relevant values, not complete vertices and edges. But yea, these are only things to think about IF you see performance issues.